# Module 'System.Data.Linq' Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, Publickeytoken=b77a5c561934e089' should be referenced

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, datacontext

I have a Visual Studio 2012 web application (fw. 4.5) where I try to linq to my sql database.
I've added a datacontext to my project and put it in the root folder. In the datacontext file I added a table named GlobalMenu from my SQL 2012 expressdatabase.

I'm trying to access the data with linq by using the following command:

```
DataContextDataContext db = new DataContextDataContext();
var menupages = from p in db.GlobalMenus
                select p;
```

Intellisense reports:

```
Module 'System.Data.Linq' Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, Publickeytoken=b77a5c561934e089' should be referenced
```

When I compile and try to run my application I get:

```
CS0012: The type 'System.Data.Linq.DataContext' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
```

System.Data.Linq 4.0.0.0 is refenced in my project and I've manually added

```
 <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Data.Linq" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.5.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
```

in runtime section in web.config.
However the error is still there.

Another problem is when I put my DataContext file into App_Code folder I get another error.

Intellisense reports:
Cannot resolve symbol 'Select'

After compiling and running the web application I get a runtime error inside the datacontext file in the designer file.

```
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;
```

> Cannot resolve symbol 'Linq'.

This web project is based on a standard "ASP.NET Web Forms Application" and what I'm trying to do is quit basic programming, so I can't see what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: if you are using mysql database then choose other technique to access data because linq to sql only supprot sql server.try it by ado or ms applicaion block

Comment: If this is a basic project then why are you trying to downgrade an assembly? Why not just use the default settings on all assemblies and references? Also, if you mark the `System.Data.Linq` reference, does it really say 4.0.0.0 in the properties window?

Comment: Vikas Rana: This is an all Microsoft software application with Visual Studio and SQL 2012 express. Because of lack of experience I want to do a Linq request to my database.

Comment: Niklas: I'm not trying to downgrade. When I greated the project System.Data.Linq added framework 4.0.0.0 by default. Not fw. 4.5. Visual Studio references C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Data.Linq.dll, but the version number under References in Visual Studio says 4.0.0.0

Answer (score 4):

This error is commonly because of a DLL version mismatch. Try deleting your `bin` folder and rebuilding the application.

Comment: I tried to delete the bin folder, but the problem was still there. I ran windows update and did a complete update on all packages.

Comment: I had this problem when I added SQLBasic file at start of project then changed to SQL Server. It added a Data.sqlCE something. Remove that reference and set data.linq to copy local. Cause it is actually missing during runtime so the view panics.

Comment: I deleted the bin and obj folders and then recompiled (build) and worked fine!!!
Of course, I did a copy of the project before doing this deletion.
Thank you.
Luis

Answer (score 3):

I believe this means that you are making reference to classes/methods that are defined in another DLL (assembly).  Your project needs to have a reference to this library (DLL/assembly) so that it can compile your project. (nothing to do with the web/app config file)

From within your project, right click on the 'References' section header and choose 'Add Reference'.  Browse to the location of the assembly (it should be under 'Assemblies->Framework->System.Data.Linq)

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

It also seems like "Linq to SQL classes" can be added to "APP_Code" folder. I was not able to query the datacontext when it was stored in APP_Code folder.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, `Restart Visual Studio` > `delete the reference` > `add the right reference again` >  `clean solution` > `rebuild solution` works.